# How to establish SSL communication be IBM MQ & the MQ java client?

Tags: ssl, ibm-mq, keystore, mq, truststore

I'm trying to connect my java based application to the IBM MQ queue manager through the MQ client. SSL is already configured at MQ Server which is managed by third-party, Now to configure the SSL on the client-side I need Keystore & Truststore in .jks form.

1. Could you please let me know the process of generating the Keystore & Truststore required for SSL communication b/w IBM MQ server & client?
2. What is the Userid in Keystore & Truststore is it the alias name?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Did you read [Using TLS with IBM MQ classes for JMS](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/ibm-mq/9.2?topic=application-using-tls-mq-classes-jms) already?

Answer (score 1):

There is a tutorial that will guide you through the process of creating a JMS Keystore - https://developer.ibm.com/tutorials/mq-secure-msgs-tls/

but it doesn't need to be. You could use a .p12 Truststore, and there is a guide that shows how - https://github.com/ibm-messaging/mq-dev-samples/blob/master/README.md

both use `keytool`.